# Maximize or Minimize a specific excel file using its name in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make an application in which I open several type of Files using vb.net and then I want to be able to minimize and maximize a specific opened  file using its name. 
The problem is that some files open as windows for the same process name for example (Excel, notepad, word, autocad).
I tried to use the process ID to control the windows but the process ID remain the same for all the files that belong to the same process.

This is the function that I use to minimize the window but it only control the Main Window of the process not a specific one

```
Public Sub Minimize(Id As Integer)
    Dim localById As Process = Process.GetProcessById(Id)
    Try

        ShowWindow(localById.MainWindowHandle, 2) ' 

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

But I really don't know how to proceed. My target is to be able to minimize or maximize a specific opened window of a process using its name.
for example if I open a word file by the name "Config.docx" and another file by the name "Specifications.docx" the two files appear in the taskmanager as "Microsoft Word (2)" and what i am trying to do is to control not only the main window of a process but each window using its name.

Can anyone Help me?

Answer (score 0):

Set the workbook as active using the index - the workbook you want to manipulate (Minimize, Maximize)

```
Private Sub btnOpenFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenFile.Click
    Dim myExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim aWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim abook1 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim abook2 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim abook3 As Excel.Workbook

    myExcel = New Excel.Application
    'index = 1
    aWorkbook = myExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Dev\Debug\Reports\2017-11-07T08_54_42_Report.xls")
    'index = 2
    abook1 = myExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Dev\Debug\Reports\2017-11-07T12_38_40_Report.xls")
    'index = 3
    abook2 = myExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Dev\Debug\Reports\2017-11-09T09_23_40_Report.xls")
    'index = 4
    abook3 = myExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Dev\Debug\Reports\2017-11-09T09_35_00_Report.xls")
    myExcel.Visible = True
    myExcel.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMinimized
    myExcel.Workbooks(3).Activate()
    Dim T As Excel.Application
    T = myExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Parent
    T.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized

    'Don't forget to cleanup excel stuff aka close it and release stuff :)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply but I think I gave a wrong explanation of my problem. I edited my question now.